# Have you gotten a job through http://stackoverflow.com/

Tags: discussion, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow Careers success stories?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35013/stack-overflow-careers-success-stories)

Or made any other financial gain?

Comment: This is exactly what Careers was designed for. http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Oh god, it's happening *again*! Flagged... pwah, I even checked, it looked like the coast was clear earlier... JON SKEET! *You* cast that extra vote!

Comment: I don't see that this is actually an exact duplicate. I'm not even *on* Stack Overflow Careers, and yet I've effectively made financial gain...

Answer (score 2):

I believe I've sold a bunch of copies of C# in Depth due to Stack Overflow - and likewise I've been invited to various speaking engagements due to the increased visibility within the community. (I don't make any money from speaking, but it's still a perk.)

Answer (score 0):

Never has job opportunity or any financial gain.